# Java Streams - Transform stream result from an object to another

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to implement a function that changes a `Stream<PersonData>` to `Stream<Person>`. As input parameter, it gets the `Stream<PersonData>` and returns the `Stream<Person>`.

PersonData is info about a person and has this form:

`{id: person1, Car: 'ford'}, {id: person1, Car: 'porsche'}, {id: person1, Car: 'seat'}`

and I want to group these three PersonDatas in one object Person. The result should be this:

`{id: person1, Cars: ['ford','porsche', 'seat']}`

I want to group by id and then create a list of Persons. I have the expression defined but now I want to transform it to a Stream

```
public static Stream<Person> getPersonById(Stream<PersonData> stream) {
    Map<String, List<String>> newMap = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonData::getID,
          Collectors.mapping(PersonData::getCarName, Collectors.toList())));
    // TODO: Transform  Map<String, List<String>> to Stream<Person>
    return newMap;
}
```

**Update**:
The constructor of Person is:

`public Person(int id, List<String> Cars) {}`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You can't really make it a `Person` object, since `Person.Car` is a `String`, whereas you have a `List<String>` as value for it. You need to use a different data type (unless you want to stringify the list)

Comment: The constructor of Person is like that sorry: `Person(int id, List<String> Cars)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The constructor of Person is like that sorry: `Person(int id, List<String> Cars)`

In this case your code should look like this :

```
return newMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Person(Integer.valueOf(e.getKey()), e.getValue()));
```

Or if you want to make it in one shot :

```
return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonData::getId,
        Collectors.mapping(PersonData::getCarName, Collectors.toList())
)).entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Person(Integer.valueOf(e.getKey()), e.getValue()));
```

---

I would also suggest to use `private Integer id;` in `PersonData` to avoid converting the String to an integer so your code will be :

```
...
.map(e -> new Person(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```